# SQL Transactions

Tags: sql, database, transactions

Probably a few easy to answer questions for you guys.  I'm just a little bit confused and could use some help.

I'm confused on how I would write a series of read/writes for a transaction.  I've seen a few examples here and there online, but there isn't much.  A lot of them aren't even explained at all.

For example, I'm trying to write out the read/write sequence for this transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION

SELECT course_id 
FROM course 
WHERE title = ‘Statistical Methods II’ 

INSERT INTO takes (id, course_id, sec_id, semester, year) 
  VALUES (12345, ‘STAT307’, 001, ‘Fall’, 2014)

COMMIT
```

If you guys could help at all, I'd appreciate it.  I might have a few questions later as well concerning a full interleaved schedule of reads/writes based on several transactions starting simultaneously.

Comment: What is the purpose of the select query?

Comment: I need to insert a record into the takes table where the course title is Statistical Methods II.  However, the only way I can find the course id is by accessing the course table and finding the id where the title is as previously mentioned.

Comment: Try combining the two statements `Insert Into takes (...) Select (...) From course Where title = '...'`

Comment: How would I write the series of read/writes though?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*series of read/writes*" in SQL terms?  If you just need "*to insert a record into the takes table*" all you need is a single `INSERT` statement as shown by `Dave Johnson`.

Comment: I need to write out the series of read/write requests required by each transaction.  I need to assume that the objects requested for reading/writing are all full tables as well.

Comment: I guess you could basically say the transaction model is what I need.